# Convert jQuery to Angular and optimize performance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found nice looking "console like" window - http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/events (start typing in box) and I'm trying to create Angular version.

My code looks like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('console', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: [
        '<div class="console animated">',
        '<div ng-repeat="event in events" ng-class="{\'error\': event.type == \'error\', \'log\': event.type == \'log\'}">{{event.data}}</div>',
        '</div>'
      ].join(''),
      link: function($scope, element) {

        $scope.events = [];

        $rootScope.$on('Log', function(event, data) {
          //console.log(event, data);
          $scope.events.splice(0, 0,{
            type: 'log',
            data: "Log :: "+data
          });
        });

        $rootScope.$on('Error', function(event, data) {
          //console.log(event, data);
          $scope.events.splice(0, 0,{
            type: 'error',
            data: "Error :: "+data
          });
        });
      }
    };
```

And I can add item to my console by calling:

```
$rootScope.$emit("Error", "Something bad happened");
```

Here is my current version: https://plnkr.co/edit/iLZKa8hPCBSRDV0dhn15?p=preview

On top is original jQuery version, on bottom in Angular version.

The thing I'm missing is event aggregation:

[image]

Original version is groupping entries and adding counter is same event occures more that once.

How can I add this to my code (Angular way)?

Besides conversion I have two more questions I'd like to ask:
-This in one of my first directives I'm writing, if I'm making any mistakes in it please let me know.
-This "console" will show many events and I'd like to know how to optimize it - should I show for example only last 20 entries or can I add functionality like virtual scroll to optimize it a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to add counter to events. This is my version of code:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .directive('console', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      template: [
        '<div class="console animated">',
        '<div ng-repeat="event in events" ng-class="{\'error\': event.type == \'error\', \'log\': event.type == \'log\'}">',
        '{{event.data}}<span ng-if="event.count>1" class="count">{{event.count}}</span>',
        '</div>',
        '</div>'
      ].join(''),
      link: function($scope, element) {

        $scope.events = [];

        $rootScope.$on('Log', function(event, data) {

          if ($scope.events[0] !== undefined && $scope.events[0].type === "log" && $scope.events[0].data === "Log :: " + data) {
            $scope.events[0].count++;
          } else {
            $scope.events.splice(0, 0, {
              type: 'log',
              data: "Log :: " + data,
              count: 1
            });
          }

        });

        $rootScope.$on('Error', function(event, data) {

          if ($scope.events[0] !== undefined && $scope.events[0].type === "error" && $scope.events[0].data === "Error :: " + data) {
            $scope.events[0].count++;
          } else {
            $scope.events.splice(0, 0, {
              type: 'error',
              data: "Error :: " + data,
              count: 1
            });
          }

        });
      }
    };
  }])
```

And [Plunker with demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/G6M3jJwHzdCsK9RF9Tab?p=preview).

I can add entry from anywhere using:

```
$rootScope.$emit("Error", "Something bad happened");
```

Hopefully someone will find it useful.